# Consuming SOAP WS in springboot returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, config

When I try to make request to SOAP web service I got error 401.

This is the error org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Unauthorized [401]

I followed these guides https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/ and https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/09/06/spring-4-soap-request-with-http-basic-authentication/

This is my configuration

SoapClientConfig file

```
import org.cryptacular.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor.ClientInterceptor;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.WebServiceMessageSender;

import java.security.KeyStore;


@Configuration
public class SoapClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller()  {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.example.test.SOAP");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServiceMessageSender webServiceMessageSender() {
        return new WebServiceMessageSenderWithAuth();
    }

    @Bean
    public SoapClient soapConnector(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller,  WebServiceMessageSender webServiceMessageSender) {
        SoapClient client = new SoapClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("https://example.test.asmx");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setMessageSender(webServiceMessageSender);
        return client;
    }

}
```

SoapClient file

```
public class SoapClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
    public CreateCaseAndActResponse createCaseAndAct(String jmbg,String subjectType, String ime,String prezime, String adresaUI, String adresaMj, String adresaPTT, String conId, String accId, Float dug, String billing) throws JAXBException, SOAPException {

        CreateCaseAndAct createCaseAndAct = new CreateCaseAndAct();

        createCaseAndAct.setJMBG(jmbg);
        createCaseAndAct.setSubjectType(subjectType);
        createCaseAndAct.setIme(ime);
        createCaseAndAct.setPrezime(prezime);
        createCaseAndAct.setAdresaUl(adresaUI);
        createCaseAndAct.setAdresaMj(adresaMj);
        createCaseAndAct.setAdresaPTT(adresaPTT);
        createCaseAndAct.setConId(conId);
        createCaseAndAct.setAccId(accId);
        createCaseAndAct.setDug(dug);
        createCaseAndAct.setBilling(billing);

        JAXBElement<CreateCaseAndAct> jAXBElement = new ObjectFactory().createCaseAndAct(createCaseAndAct);

        CreateCaseAndActResponse aXBElementResponse = (CreateCaseAndActResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive( "https://example.test.asmx", jAXBElement, new SoapActionCallback("https://test.asmx/createCaseAndAct"));
        return aXBElementResponse;

    }
}
```

SoapController file

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1", produces =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class SoapController extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
    @Autowired
    private SoapClient soapClient;


    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/createCaseAndAct")
    public CreateCaseAndActResponse createCaseAndAct(@RequestParam String jmbg,
                                                     @RequestParam String subjectType,
                                                     @RequestParam String ime,
                                                     @RequestParam String prezime,
                                                     @RequestParam String adresaUI,
                                                     @RequestParam String adresaMj,
                                                     @RequestParam String adresaPTT,
                                                     @RequestParam String conId,
                                                     @RequestParam String accId,
                                                     @RequestParam Float dug,
                                                     @RequestParam String billing) throws JAXBException, SOAPException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        CreateCaseAndActResponse createCaseAndActResponse =  new CreateCaseAndActResponse();

        createCaseAndActResponse = soapClient.createCaseAndAct(jmbg,subjectType, ime,prezime, adresaUI, adresaMj, adresaPTT, conId, accId, dug, billing);

        return createCaseAndActResponse;

    }
}
```

and WebServiceMessageSenderWithAuth file

```
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.util.Base64;

public class WebServiceMessageSenderWithAuth extends HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender {

    @Override
    protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
        String userpassword = "username:password";
        String encodedAuthorization = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(userpassword.getBytes());
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthorization);

        super.prepareConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

Any help please?